# Digest Authentication in Swift using Alamofire

Tags: swift, digest-authentication, alamofire

I have changed the Alamofire example code to try to support Digest Authentication but cannot get it to work.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController.topViewController as? DetailViewController {
        func requestForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) -> Request? {
            switch segue.identifier {
                case "GET":
                    let user = "Administrator"
                    let password = "password"

                    let credential = NSURLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: .ForSession)
                    let protectionSpace = NSURLProtectionSpace(host: "172.16.0.56", port: 443, `protocol`: "https", realm: "myrealm", authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPDigest)
                    return Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://172.16.0.56")
                        .authenticate(usingCredential: credential, forProtectionSpace: protectionSpace)
                        .response {(request, response, _, error) in
                            println(response)
                }
                default:
                    return nil
            }
        }

        if let request = requestForSegue(segue) {
            detailViewController.request = request
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this code then I get the following response:

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fa0c3525320> { URL: https://172.16.0.56/ } { status code: 401, headers {
"Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 163;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Wed, 17 Sep 2014 16:45:29 GMT";
Expires = 0;
Server = "MyServer";
"Www-Authenticate" = "Digest realm=\"myrealm\", nonce=\"4642875290551863156110287\", algorithm=\"MD5\", qop=\"auth\", stale=\"FALSE\"";
} })
```

It seems that Alamofire makes no attempt to send the user name and password back to the server hashed with the nonce returned and I just get the 'Not Authorised' page back from the server. Is Alamofire supposed to do the digest authentication on my behalf or is there more code that I need to write myself?

Answer (score 2):

[Digest Authentication works just as expected in the latest version of Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/4771fad488e64c0f7373d0acc8e7a31073a16eee/Tests/AuthenticationTests.swift#L64-L100).

Comment: yes I tried again and everything worked. I got it working following the basic authentication method rather than the above. Your authentication tests were useful for working this out. Thanks. Still got problems linking AlamoFire into my project, but I'll post this as another question if I'm still having problems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
  let userNameValue = "user"
    let passwordValue = "passwd"
    let credential = URLCredential(user: userNameValue, password: passwordValue, persistence: .forSession)
    let sessionMananager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    _ = sessionMananager.request("http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(userNameValue)/\(passwordValue)")
        .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))")
            print("Result: \(response.result)")

            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print("this is jsn: \(json)")
    }
}
```